# Ajax Call won't run PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have been trying  to make an ajax call to run a php script but it refuses to do so even though it did work a few days ago. ajax function:

```
function passDownToPhp(mystring1, mystring2)
    {
    $.ajax 
    ({
    url:"addUserHandling.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {username: mystring1, password: mystring2},
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) 
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the php script EDIT(quotation problem, script should work now):

```
<?php
include_once "conf.php";
$myusername =$_POST['username'];
$mypassword =$_POST['password'];
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$myusername', '$mypassword')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$user_id= mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$query = "INSERT INTO profile (username,password,email,user_id) VALUES ('lala','lala','lala','$user_id')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//Redirect('profile.php');
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script>alert("ok")</script>';
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    //echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    echo '<script>alert("sql problem")</script>';
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The debugging processes i have already follown is sending an alert right before i call the ajax function witch works perfectly fine, the conf.php file IS working since when i log on into the site(session based) i can communicate with my db, and have tried different browsers/flushed cache to no avail. The changes i have made to the site prior to the problem's occurance are :
a) connecting the user_id Primary key (auto_incriment) from users table with a secondary key in the profile table
b) after i noticed the problem i added the second query in my php file.

Comment: You have quote issues in your php that will cause a parse error -> `echo '<script>alert('ok')</script>';` && `echo '<script>alert('sql problem')</script>';
}`. You need to change either the inner or outer `'` to `"`

Comment: If you look at this line `echo '<script>alert('ok')</script>';` you have single quotes within single quotes which will cause an error. Check your error log and replace either outer or inner with double quotes or escape inner quotes with a backslash.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what status is. Suspect it's 500. If so, add error handling in php and see what response body reads in network request response body or look in server log files

Comment: @charlietfl, what do you mean please by `error handling if status is 500`?

Comment: i seriously feel so dumb right now... the quotation solved my problem. I will update my post as well. Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: I highly recommend you learn where your PHP installation is logging errors so you can check that file first when your script breaks.  It probably seems like an annoyance that slows you down when you just want to code, but it will save you SO much time in the long run.

Comment: and learn how to display errors for debugging. error handling is easy to research. Writing code is only 1/2 the battle...learning how to debug it is the other 1/2 and should take higher priority to learn about the tools used